# Ubuntu - Get audio over optical cable

Tags: ubuntu, audio, drivers, optical-cable

Is it possible to play audio over optical cables in Ubuntu?

I've got a motherboard with Realtek ALC888 onboard audio.   Ubuntu can play music/sounds just fine to my headphones or over analog cables to my speakers.

However, my problem is that I use an optical cable for my speakers (Logitech Z-5500).   This works great when I am booted into windows, but so far I have been unable to get it working over the optical cable.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1130928

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=776958

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable three settings to get it to work:

Make IEC958 output captured from PCM.

[image]

Make IEC958 the new default PCM output:

[image]

Raise the volume, unmute and enjoy!

[image]

All those options will be available if driver has support for it and you have those options enabled under volume control.

Comment: Please can you describe where to set those 3 options.